# MySQL - subtracting row 2 from row 1 where column is the same

Tags: mysql, function

I am creating a temp table which currently pulls values in for today and yesterday. The temp table looks like this:

```
|DateTime                |company 1 |company 2 |
+------------------------+----------------------+
|2013-10-03 14:40:00     | 182475   |  110271  |
|2013-10-02 14:10:00     | 182086   |  110261  |
```

What I need to do is select the values from today, as well as the difference between today and yesterday. Based on the above data, the output would look like this:

```
Company 1   | Company 1 difference | Company 2|  Company 2 difference
+-----------+----------------------+----------+--------------------------
182475      |         389          | 110271   |          10
```

I can't figure out how to specify which row to subtract from which, since there is no auto-increment field and the DateTime field will be slightly different each day.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It's an odd structure to have each company as a separate column rather than, for example, `(Date, CompanyNumber, Amount)`.  In any event, are the amounts strictly increasing with respect to time, such that one can simple use `MAX()-MIN()`?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT today.DateTime as DateTime
  , today.Company1, today.Company1 - COALESCE(yesterday.Company1,0) AS Company1Diff
  , today.Company2, today.Company2 - COALESCE(yesterday.Company2,0) AS Company2Diff
FROM tbl AS today
LEFT JOIN tbl AS yesterday
ON DATEDIFF(today.DateTime, yesterday.DateTime) = 1
ORDER BY today.DateTime ASC
```

Comment: Very nice! A couple things: (1) `LEFT JOIN tbl AS yesterday WHERE ...` should be `LEFT JOIN tbl AS yesterday ON ...` (ON instead of WHERE), and (2) note the difference in time of day in the sample data - the join expression needs to compare on date only rather than date and time, so I'd suggest `WHERE DATEDIFF(DATE(today.DateTime), DATE(yesterday.DateTime)) = 1`.

Comment: The WHERE vs ON was a typo.  But I don't think the DATE() is required. (Probably minimal overhead, but none the the less not required.)  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

Comment: You're right - `DATE()` is not required. I didn't know about the "date part only" for `DATEDIFF`; thanks for pointing this out :)